# How to use Mozilla CA Certificate as ssl client certificate

Tags: php, ssl, stream-socket-client

My php code need to connect to a remote ssl server using stream_socket_client(), The ssl server owner provide me this document:

> All clients must use a publicly verifiable certificate. We support a
>   wide range of public certificate authorities. All those in the Mozilla
>   CA Certificate Store (as used in the Firefox browser and Debian
>   operating systems), are supported as well as the free public
>   certificate authority CACert (www.cacert.com).

I do know I can use stream_context_create() with "local_cert" and "local_pk" to provide my client certificate.

As they mention of www.cacert.com, I can download certificate files from http://www.cacert.org/index.php?id=3

My question is: With the certificate files I downloaded from www.cacert.org, what need to be set for "local_cert" and "local_pk"?

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge is improved after this, here is what I did to get over:

I used "*WHM SSL/TLS »Generate an SSL Certificate and Signing Request*" tool to generate Signing Request, Certificate and **Private Key**, then submit them all to CAcert.org, and they generate me a **SSL certificate**.

Then use **SSL certificate** as "local_cert", **Private Key** as "local_pk" and everything works well.